# Multiplying multiple texboxes

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a menu application, I have at the moment 3 textboxes, textbox1 is price, textbox2 is quantity and textbox3 is total. I have successfully written the code to calculate the price of an item depending on the quantity they need. The code i have right now:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox8.Text = CStr(Val(TextBox6.Text) * Val(TextBox7.Text))
End Sub
```

Now what I need is that I will have more items say 10 along with textboxes beside as quantity which makes 20 textboxes and one total textbox. How can I write the code so that it calculates every textbox as well as null values say if out of the 10 items i want only 2 items 1 per quantity into the total value.

Thanks

Comment: use a `List<int>` instead and store your textbox values. Then compute using that list in a `foreach`

Comment: To start begin naming your textboxes in a comprensible way: I.E. txtTotal1, txtQuantity1, txtPrice1 and so on for product 2etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i strongly suggest to use .NET methods instead of old VB methods. I also would set `OPTION STRICT` to `On` in general which avoids "magical" conversions done for you by the runtime. Instead you have to specify the correct types which is a good thing since it can prevent errors on runtime and it also helps to learn the .NET types and methods.

I would add those TextBoxes all to the  same container-control (like a `Panel` or something similar). I also suggest to use more meaningful names for your controls(f.e. `TxtTotal` for the total-textbox).

So if all price-textboxes' names start with `TxtPrice` (f.e. `TxtPrice1` etc) and all quantity-TextBoxes start with `TxtQuantity` (f.e. `TxtQuantity1` etc), this LINQ query approach will work:

```
Dim allTextBoxes = PriceQuantityPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
Dim allPrices = From txt In allTextBoxes
                Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TxtPrice") 
Dim allQuantities = From txt In allTextBoxes
                    Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TxtQuantity")
Dim price As Decimal
Dim invalidPrices = From txt In allPrices
                    Where Not Decimal.TryParse(txt.Text, price)
If invalidPrices.Any() Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid prices(Decimal)!")
    Return
End If
Dim quantity As Int32
Dim invalidQuantities = From txt In allQuantities
                        Where Not Int32.TryParse(txt.Text, quantity)
If invalidQuantities.Any() Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid quantities(Integer)!")
    Return
End If
```

Now you can "join" the pairs of price and quantity textboxes by the number-suffix:

```
Dim query = From txtP In allPrices
            Join txtQ In allQuantities
            On txtP.Name.Substring("TxtPrice".Length) Equals txtQ.Name.Substring("TxtQuantity".Length)
            Select New With {.Price = Decimal.Parse(txtP.Text), .Quantity = Int32.Parse(txtQ.Text)}

Dim totalSum As Decimal = query.Sum(Function(x) x.Price * x.Quantity)
TxtTotal.Text = totalSum.ToString()
```

Comment: does this work if the txtprice textboxes have default values in already?

Comment: Yes it does, why not?